# Can't wakeup Raspberry Pi if unused for more than a day

Tags: power

I'm using Raspberry Pi to run [Onion Share](https://onionshare.org/) and ProtonVPN on a CanaKit Raspberry Pi 4. I check it once a day. Moving the mouse wakes it up. But if I miss a day, moving the mouse does not wake it up. Likewise for the keyboard. So I have to unplug it and boot up again.

Any idea how I can avoid having to unplug it and can just keep waking it up by moving the mouse?

Thanks!

Comment: it sounds like a linux question, not a Raspberry Pi question

Comment: @jsotola sleep/wakeup issues could be HW-dependent

Comment: @jsotola I have a Pi 3b in a warm room in a Pi case that would become unresponsive frequently.  ssh would give a weird error and not let me connect.  I opened the top of the case and it has been up for over a month now, I assume it was an overheating issue.

Comment: even overheating issues are not really Raspberry Pi specific ... the issue can happen with any hardware

Comment: it may be a Raspberry Pi issue, but a possibke Linux issue should be explored first

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your mouse/keyboard can't wake up from a long sleep. Try re-plugging them into USB. If that helps, you could write a `udev` rule for it with `ATTR{power/control}:="on"`. Or just get a different mouse.

If this is indeed your Pi that won't wake up, figure out whether it's running at all. Try to SSH into it for instance. If the Pi is unresponsive, you could try setting up a watchdog.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry! Problem occurs with the keyboard as well, as it doesn't seem to matter what USB port the mouse is plugged into. I'll take a shot at SSH. Thanks again!